# Do static member functions add an overhead to the class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, methods, static

I want to provide static helper functions to handle the data type of a class. I considered including them in the class itself. Would they be instantiated for every new class instance or just once?

Comment: Neither static nor instance methods are 'instantiated'. There is no overhead in the sense you are thinking of.

Comment: The overhead comes from initializing static members, which needs to happen for all static objects before the program is run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Functions are not "instantiated"** (unless they are function *templates*).

*Classes* are instantiated, and instances of classes are *objects*. Each object takes space in memory, but functions are just procedures, pieces of code generated once and for all by the compiler, and space for them in memory is not allocated every time a new object is instantiated.

Functions can implicitly work on an instance of a class (if the function is a member function), but that's done just by passing a implicit pointer to the object they work on. Even in the case of member functions, therefore, be them `static` or non-`static`, there's no proliferation of pieces of code<sup>1</sup>.

If you meant to ask whether only one piece of code is produced for `static` functions, rather than several separate pieces of code, then the answer is "**Yes**"; but then again the answer is the same for member functions.

<sup>1</sup> Actually, `virtual` member functions do require storing an additional pointer for every instance of a class that has at least one member `virtual` function (this pointer would point to the so-called *vtable*). However, `static` functions cannot be `virtual`, so this does not apply to the case you are considering in the question.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no per-instance overhead associated with `static` member functions.

Furthermore, there is no per-instance overhead associated with **any** member functions, with one exception. The exception is adding a virtual function to a class that didn't have any; typically, this would add an extra pointer to every instance of the class. Adding more virtual functions would incur no further per-instance overhead.

Comment: With the qualification that adding a virtual function to a class that didn't previously have any will typically add a pointer into the data of objects of that type.

Answer (score 1):

Member functions (static or otherwise) are only ever instantiated once. They never add any overhead to the class under any circumstances.

Comment: `virtual`s do. Perhaps only first one.

Comment: @zch They don't. Having a vtable adds a pointer, but the individual members functions, as well as the vtable, only exist once and their amount and size has no bearing on the size of the instances. Yes, could have mentioned that, but I don't see it remotely justifying a downvote (+1 to counter).

Comment: Even a virtual function is only 'instantiated' once.

Comment: Functions are not instantiated. Classes are, structs are, primitive types are. But not functions.

Comment: @delnan, I agree. I'm just pointing out that adding function can affect object size. I don't think this answer deserves downvotes.